# Move labeled subset of Gmail messages to another account

Tags: gmail, google-account, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, import

I want to move my messages from one Gmail account to another, but not all and that is the problem. All manuals in the web shows how to set up [forwarding/import](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en&ref_topic=7280290) that moves **all messages**, but I don't want to do that, I want to move messages by some label.

I tried [email import feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en&ref_topic=7280290) making source messages unread beforehand, but anyway it imported all mailbox, both read and unread.

Is there a way to more fine-grained import?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Outlook client? You can drag messages from one mailbox to another with that client.

Comment: No, unfortunately no. I have only Win10 built-in client.

Comment: AFAIK there is no built-in feature to do that. You could use an IMAP email client, the Gmail API / Google Apps Script or a third party tool.

Comment: it is very generic comment. I know that I should use a 3rd tool or a script but I need details: exact Google Apps script, not just comment